# How to Prove a Metric Space is Sequential?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, real-numbers

Let's say I have a space X with a "d-metric" on X, a function d:X×X→R that has the following 2 properties:

d(x,y)≥0 for all x, y∈X and

d(x,x)=0 for all x, y∈X.

The d-ball of radius r centered at x is defined as Br(x)={y∈X:d(x,y) < r}

We'll say the topological space (X,T) is d-metrizable if there is a function d such that U is in T if and only if for all x in U there exists a d-ball centered at x which is contained in U.

How can I prove that "d-metrizable" spaces are sequential?

Note:  Sequential means every sequentially open set is open (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_space).